# variable between two visual page with the same controller

Tags: variable

I have a controller like that :

```
public  with sharing class JSONDeserialize {

public integer d {get;set;}

}

public void callout() {
d = 2;
}
```

On my first visual page I have :

```
<apex:page controller="JSONDeserialize">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="AKTARUS" />
        <apex:pageBlock title="JSON Deserialize Response">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Callout" action="{!callout}" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline!='1'}"/>

  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
{!d}
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Which work perfectly fine, when I call the button I can see the variable d displaying

The goal would be to have a second visual page like that :

```
<apex:page controller="JSONDeserialize" >
{!d}
</apex:page>
```

And when I click on the callout button from page1 it display the variable d (which is 2) on the second page.

I tried to do a function like that :

```
public Pagereference callout(){
d=2;
PageReference oPageRef = Page.Cyril;
    oPageRef.setRedirect(false);

    return oPageRef;
}
```

Which is working (variable d get display) but I don't want to be redirected to the second page from the first one.

Is there any way to just pass the variable without redirection, click on the button from page one and refresh page 2 and get the variable displayed.

Of course here the function and pages are simplified, but it is to get the concept behind.

Comment: That's how the web works. You need to be redirected.

Comment: Yes but the goal is then to send the visual page 2 as an email.

Comment: That's an entirely different problem. You'd need to pass the parameters to get it to work correctly.